# Q: how to refactor repeating if block code with properties as much as possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i would like to compact the following repeating code with property access as much as possible into a for loop or using functions:

```
    if (sender == self.section1SegmentedControl) {
        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: //YES
                self.DSProtokoll.section1YesNo = TRUE;
                break;
            case 1: //NO
                self.DSProtokoll.section1YesNo = FALSE;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (sender == self.section2SegmentedControl) {
        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: //YES
                self.DSProtokoll.section2YesNo = TRUE;
                break;
            case 1: //NO
                self.DSProtokoll.section2YesNo = FALSE;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (sender == self.section3SegmentedControl) {
        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: //YES
                self.DSProtokoll.section3YesNo = TRUE;
                break;
            case 1: //NO
                self.DSProtokoll.section3YesNo = FALSE;
                break;
        }
    }
```

i tried putting it in a function:

```
- (void)processYesNoIfMatch:(UISegmentedControl *)sender source:(UISegmentedControl *) a dest:(BOOL *) b {
    if (sender == a) {
        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0: //YES
                *b = TRUE;
                break;
            case 1: //NO
                *b = FALSE;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

but i cannot use the function and calling it several times with different arguments:

```
[self processYesNoIfMatch:sender source:self.section1SegmentedControl dest:&self.DSProtokoll.section1YesNo];
[self processYesNoIfMatch:sender source:self.section2SegmentedControl dest:&self.DSProtokoll.section2YesNo];
```

because pointers to properties are not allowed with

> Address of property expression requested

how to simpify this repeating original code in objective-c with functions or for loop as much as possible?

Comment: The `switch` statement can be replaced with `self.DSProtokoll.section1YesNo = (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);`

Comment: Since this question has (incorrectly, IMO) been closed as “opinion-based”, I can only respond in a comment. Here's a reasonable refactoring, assuming `self.DSProtokoll` is of type `DSProtokoll`: `BOOL setting = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0; DSProtokoll *p = self.DSProtokoll; if (sender == self.section1SegmentedControl) { p.section1YesNo = setting; } else if (sender == self.section2SegmentedControl) { p.section2YesNo = setting; } else if (sender == self.section3SegmentedControl) { p.section3YesNo = setting;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C methods calls use *dynamic binding* and provided you are happy to trade some compile-time checking for possible runtime errors you can shorten your code considerably. Treat the following as *pseudocode* (as it has been typed directly into the answer and is only a fragment of code):

```
for(int controlNumber = 1; controlNumber <= MAX_CONTROL_NUMBER; controlNumber++)
{
   // construct the property name as a *string*
   NSString *controlProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section%dSegmentedControl", controlNumber);
   // get the property value - if the property does not exist this is a runtime error
   NSSegmentedControl *controlN = [self valueForKey:controlProperty];
   if (sender == controlN)
   {
      // construct the property path as a *string*
      NSString *yesNoProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DSProtokoll.section%dYesNo", controlNumber;
      // set the property value, must pass the BOOL as an NSNumber object
      [self setValue:@(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) forKeyPath:yesNoProperty];
      // all done, exit loop
      break;
   }
}
```

There are other ways to tackle this problem. Your particular attempt failed only because you tried to take the address of a property as if it was a *variable*; a property is a pair of functions, a getter and setter, and you can take the address of these functions and pass them to other functions to call. However you would probably find it easier to pass a *block* which sets the property rather than a function pointer to the property setter. With such a change your `processYesNoIfMatch` method would work.

HTH